# Constructing bijections between closed connected intervals of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

So today in my Algebraic Topology class we were trying to construct a homotopy and at one point we needed to basically construct a (continuous) bijection between some intervals $[a, b]$ and $[c, d]$ sending $a \mapsto c$ and $b \mapsto d$.

My professor said that a bijection $\varphi : [a, b] \to [c, d]$ would be a linear function of the form $\varphi(x) = \alpha x + \beta$ and adding the contraints that $\varphi(a) = c$ and $\varphi(b) = d$ we get a linear system of equations $$\alpha \cdot a + \beta = c$$ $$\alpha \cdot b + \beta =d.$$

Solving this system we get $$\alpha = \frac{c-d}{a-b}$$ and $$\beta=\frac{ad-bc}{a-b}$$

so that $\varphi$ is given by $$\varphi(x) = \left(\frac{c-d}{a-b}\right)x + \frac{ad-bc}{a-b}$$

---

Now I was not aware that we could construct a (continuous!) bijection between connected closed intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ so easily. My question is how exactly did my professor know that such a (continuous) bijection would be a linear function of the above form? I've never seen any theorem of the sort or something similar written in any textbook.

Comment: Draw the graph.  Put $[a,b]$ on the $x$-axis and $[c,d]$ on the $y$.  Draw a straight line.  You don't need a theorem.

Comment: The theorem follows because linear maps can take 2 points to any other two points.  Thus you can take $\{a,b\}$ to $\{c,d\}$, and let connectedness take care of the rest.

Comment: Well, $[c,d]$ is, in some sense, a translated (the coefficent $\beta$) and stretched (the coefficient $\alpha$) version of $[a,b]$, so you could expect the bijection to be a linear map.

Comment: A continuous bijection isn't necessarily linear, but since all you needed was to construct one, a linear function suffices.

Comment: Frankly, I'm astonished that you are surprised.  It should be intuitively obvious that one can "stretch" and "slide" $[a,b]$ so that it is imposed over $[c,d]$ and everything inbetween "follows proportionally".  Your professor is just doing the math that would make that happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be intuitively clear you can "stretch" and "slide" any two interval to overlap.

So to "stretch" $[a,b]$ to be as long as $[c,d]$ you just have to multiply each of the $x \in [a,b]$ by $\frac {\text{length of }[c,d]}{\text{length of }[a,b]} = \frac {d-c}{b-a}$ to get the point $x *\frac {d-c}{b-a}\in [a*\frac {d-c}{b-a}, b*\frac {d-c}{b-a}]$ which will have a length of $b*\frac {d-c}{b-a} - a*\frac {d-c}{b-a}= \frac {d-c}{b-a}(b - a) = d-c$.

And to "slide" it, we need to slide the point $a*\frac {d-c}{b-a}$ to $c$ so we need to add $c - a*\frac {d-c}{b-a}$ so that the point $x *\frac {d-c}{b-a}$ gets slid to $x *\frac {d-c}{b-a} + (c - a*\frac {d-c}{b-a})=\frac {d-c}{b-a}x + \frac {c(b-a) - a(d-c)}{b-a} = \frac {c-d}{b-a}x + \frac {cb-ad}{b-a}$

So that's your bijection.

===

Perhaps an even easier way to see it, is to take Randall's sugestion in the comments.  On a $x,y$ cartesian plane look at the rectangular section of $[a,b]$ in the $x$ axis and $[c,d]$ in the $y$ access.  Now just draw a line from one corner to the other.  That line will be your bijection.

(I'll be honest.  I *never* thought of this.  It's.... trivially easy.  But... I never came up with it on my own.)

(The slope of the line is $\frac {d-c}{b-a}$ and it contains the point $(a,c)$ so the equation of the line is $y- c = \frac {d-c}{b-a}(x-a)$ which becomes $y = f(x) = \frac {c-d}{b-a}x + \frac {cb-ad}{b-a}$)

====

I suppose the way that is most into intuitive for *me* is:

A point $x \in [a,b]$ is some proportion $t$ of the length of $[a,b]$ past $a$.  That is $x = a + t*(b-a)$ for some real number $0 \le t \le 1$.

We want to transfer $x = a + t(b-a)$ to a point that is the same proportion of of the length of $[c,d]$ past $c$.  That is we want to map $x = a+t(b-a) \mapsto c + t(d-c)$.

A little bit of algebra and we get $t = \frac {x-a}{b-a}$ and so we want to map $x \mapsto c + \frac {x-a}{b-a}(d-c) = \frac {d-c}{b-a}x + (c - a\frac {d-c}{b-a})=  \frac {c-d}{b-a}x + \frac {cb-ad}{b-a}$

Answer (score 1):

Here are two pieces of knowledge which, if you possess them and put them together, will tell you that a linear formula like this must exist.

1. Given two closed intervals $I,J \subset \mathbb R$, there is a similarity transformation of the real line $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(I)=J$.

Just to be clear about the definition, to say that $f$ is a similarity transformation means that it stretches distances by a uniform amount, i.e. there is a constant $a>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| = a |x-y|$. If you have ever studied Euclidean geometry then you might be familiar with similarity transformations, this is just the 1-dimensional version. Given $I$ and $J$ the constant $a$, of course, is just the length of $J$ divided by the length of $I$.

2. The similarity transformations of the real line are precisely the first degree polynomials, i.e. the transformations of the form $f(x)=\alpha x + \beta$ with coefficients $\alpha \in \mathbb R - \{0\}$ and $\beta \in \mathbb R$.

This is not very hard to prove: if $f(x)=\alpha x + \beta$ prove that it is a similarity transformation with stretch constant $a = |\alpha|$; and if $f(x)$ is a similarity transformation with stretch constant $a$ then set $\beta = f(0)$, and prove that either $f(x)= a x + \beta$ or $f(x) = -ax + \beta$.

Answer (score 1):

Think in stages:

i)  $\,f_1(x) = x-a$ takes $[a,b]$ to $[0,b-a].$

ii) $\,f_2(x) = x/(b-a)$ takes $[0,b-a]$ to $[0,1].$

iii) $\,f_3(x) = (d-c)x$ takes $[0,1]$ to $[0,d-c].$

iv)  $\,f_4(x) = x+c$ takes $[0,d-c]$ to $[c,d].$

The map $f_4\circ f_3 \circ f_2 \circ f_1$ then does the job.